# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in templates/results.html:13: ValueError

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a Text Classification NLP problem. I have trained the model and using the trained model for classification. Prediction data is an ordered dictionary on which predictions needs to be done.

Prediction Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Subject: fwd : next tuesday at ', 'SPAM'), ('Subject: visit may 4 th  vince ', 'SPAM'), ('Subject: enjoy media ( ejym ) e', 'SPAM')])
```

I am saving it as json file and then loading it in a display function for rendering using render_template

```
with open('labels.json', 'w') as fp:
 json.dump(result,fp)
f = open('labels.json')
predict = json.load(f)
return render_template("result.html",predictions=predict)
```

Template not rendering with the json values: Error-

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)  in templates
```

Test case Failure:

```
    {% for email, result in predictions %}
    E   ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
    code/templates/results.html:13: ValueError
```

labels.json

```
{"Subject: fwd : next tuesday at ": "SPAM", "Subject: visit may 4 th  vince ": "SPAM", "Subject: enjoy media ( ejym ) e": "SPAM"}
```

Comment: i would suggest debugging `prediction` by displaying its values for each prediction inside template , it seems it is returning more than 2 values which you're trying to extract from it `for email, result in prediction`

Comment: Actually, yes it's doing the same way in the html filebut somehow it's not able to render the json content. Can you suggest a different approach here.

Comment: can u post your json format that you're expecting to be in `prediction` , also each item in `prediction` is `dict` so you can utilize it accordingly

Comment: Thanks Atif for your inputs. I was able to render the results in proper format with the approah mentioned by Dauros below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.items()` on the dict to create a list of tuples of `(email, result)`:

```
{% for email, result in predictions.items() %}
```

Edit: Since you mentioned the template files are fixed, you can also alter the template variable and apply `.items()` there:

```
return render_template("result.html",predictions=predict.items())
```

Comment: Can you suggest a different approach as I am working on an environment and the template files are fixed and I cannot alter the code for the html files.

Comment: Sure, I've edited my answer. It does not matter where you apply the `.items()` method to the dict, you can do it in the view function as well.

Comment: Thanks @Dauros it was indeed the issue. With .items() in view funtion I was able to render the results in proper format.

Comment: @lazyEval Great! Side note: I personally really appreciate the "thank you" comments, however the official recommendation here is to accept the answer if it solved your problem. The mods usually removes the "thank you" comments anyways. Marking an answer as 'accepted' also helps others finding a solution to a similar problem.